# Getting Table Lock (MyIsam) using Nhibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

Using Nhibernate how can I get "TABLE LOCKS"

What I'd like to do is somwthing like this:

```
TABLE LOCKS table1;
update counter= 1 + counter from table1 where id=1;
select counter from table1 where id=1;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Ouch, sorry, looks like MyIsam doesn't support transactions. Removed my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run this before your query:

```
var command = session.Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "TABLE LOCKS table1";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And the corresponding UNLOCK afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! Finally what I used :
command.CommandText = "LOCK TABLES table1 WRITE";